# HTML DOM replace Comma with a Dot

Tags: php, html, dom

Im using an HTML DOM this is the code:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://www.funda.nl/beoordelingenwidget/live/16186/3/3%3d33%3b6%3d62/aankoop/');
echo $html->find(".user-reviews-averages-number", 0);
?>
```

The output is: 9,4 **but i want it to be 9.3**

I tried this:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_replace(',', '.', $html);
$html = file_get_html('https://www.funda.nl/beoordelingenwidget/live/16186/3/3%3d33%3b6%3d62/aankoop/');
echo $html->find(".user-reviews-averages-number", 0);
?>
```

But that doesn't work. Can somebody tell me what i need to do?

Kind regards.

Comment: Store your `$html->find(..)` in a variable and `str_replace()` that variable? (`$html = str_replace(',', '.', $html);` won't work because `$html` will be overwritten in the next line)

Answer (score 2):

If you just use...

```
echo $html->find(".user-reviews-averages-number", 0);
```

your full output is actually

```
<span class="user-reviews-averages-number is-high">                      9,<sup>4</sup>                  </span>
```

I'm also not sure why you call `str_replace` before you even get the HTML, but to do it properly you need to get this after you've the element you want.  Here I use `text()` on that node to get the `9,4` and then replace the `,` with a `.`...

```
// Fetch the node itself
$raw = $html->find(".user-reviews-averages-number", 0);
// extract just the value
echo str_replace(",", ".", trim($raw->innertext()));
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but i want to keep the <sup>

Comment: @RobMaathuis I've changed the `text()` call to `innertext()`.